# Gravar dados de array

Tags: php

Existe algum método mais simplificado para isso, ou essa solução é a mais correta? Tem algumas tabelas que tenho diversos campos e aí fica um pouco mais trabalhoso. Minha dúvida é se tenho que declarar todas as variáveis para depois passar para o array ou existe alguma outra maneira de simplificar?

```
<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Controllers\Controller\Create;
$Create = new Create;
$campo = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

$prodOperadora = $campo['produtoOperadora'];
$prodGB = $campo['produtoGB'];
$prodPreco = $campo['produtoPreco'];
$prodPConv = $campo['produtoPrecoConv'];
$prodDesc = $campo['produtoDesc'];
$prodOferta = $campo['produtoOferta'];
$prodStatus = $campo['produtoStatus'];

$Dados = array(
    'produtoOperadora' => $prodOperadora,
    'produtoGB' => $prodGB,
    'produtoPreco' => $prodPreco,
    'produtoPrecoConv' => $prodPConv,
    'produtoDesc' => $prodDesc,
    'produtoOferta' => $prodOferta,
    'produtoStatus' => $prodStatus
);

if($Create->getSyntax('tb_produto', $Dados)):
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show p-3">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Produto</strong> cadastrado com sucesso!
          </div>
    ';
else:
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show p-3">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Erro</strong> ao cadastrar no banco!
          </div>
    ';
endif;
```

Comment: Calma, você passa os dados de um array para variáveis e depois das variáveis para um array? Por quê já não utiliza o array original, sem definir as variáveis?

Comment: Em cadastros simples, você pode colocar o name nos campos do formulário cadastro com o mesmo nome que está no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem duas maneiras que vejo pra fazer isso:

```
$dados = [];
foreach ($campo as $key => $value) {
    $dados[$key] => $value;
 }
```

ou

```
$dados = [
    'prodOperadora' => $campo['produtoOperadora'],
    'prodPreco' => $campo['produtoPreco'],
    // e assim por diante
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para simplificar seu código, você pode fazer isso:

```
<?php 
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Controllers\Controller\Create;
$Create = new Create; $campo = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
if($Create->getSyntax('tb_produto', $campo)):
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show p-3"> <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Produto</strong> cadastrado com sucesso! </div> ';
else: 
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show p-3"> <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Erro</strong> ao cadastrar no banco! </div> ';
endif;
```